# Limit entry in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, limit, tkinter-entry

I've created some simple functions to limit my entry, but I'm a little bit stuck:
first of all `def lowercase_letter_entry` is not working and it do not edit my entry in lowercase. Second the functions that work they only do so once, after that they are kinda useless. I did try to solve this with `for` and `while true` but I've only managed to make repeat an infinity of time the warning message.
Also I know is kinda of a dumb question but right now I'm using the function changing my_entry in what variable I need. Is there a way to make the def "neutral" and make them work with all my entry without having to edit the name? (hope I've menage to make a little of sense.

```
import tkinter  
from tkinter import messagebox

def lowercase_letter_entry(P):
   if P.isalpha() or P == "":
     if P.islower():
        return True
     else:
      if not P.islower():
       P.get()lower()
       return True
   else:
    messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Only letters are allowed")
    return False
```

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The validation function must always return `True` or `False` or it will disable itself. You have many cases where it will return `None`.

> Is there a way to make the def "neutral" and make them work with all my entry without having to edit the name?

They are that way by default. You shouldn't be calling `my_entry.get()` inside the function. Your `P` parameter contains the string you should be validating against, there's no need to explicitly fetch it.

Comment: Thank you everything works except the entry that is not edited in lowercase and I can't figure why not. I edited my code in my first questions. Thanks

Comment: @CarloMarrone: calling `P.lower()` accomplishes nothing. The validation function function is designed for validation, not for modifying the data as it is being typed.